# Removing rows that include NA in specific column only if the rows are duplicate (Based on two other columns)

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame which is the result of the left join. Sample data is provided below:

```
   P.I.D..     Status List.year CURRENT_LAND_VALUE CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE
   <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>              <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1 003-913-627 X           2000                 NA                        NA
 2 003-913-627 T           2010            1578000                   1201000
 3 003-913-627 S           2018                 NA                        NA
 4 003-913-627 S           2018            2814000                    901000
 5 003-913-627 S           2002                 NA                        NA
 6 003-913-627 T           2007             390000                    282000
 7 003-913-627 T           2007             295000                    180000
 8 003-913-627 S           2008             464000                    391000
 9 003-913-627 S           2008             339000                    246000
10 003-913-627 X           2009             339000                    246000
11 003-913-627 X           2009             464000                    391000
```

**Sorry, I tried to use`dput` to generate code for the data but when I tried, it gave me some unrelated result which doesn't represent the table shown above**

As can be seen for **year** 2018 and **PID** 003-913-627, two rows are shown. One has a number for **CURRENT_LAND_VALUE** and **CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE** and one row includes NA. What I want to do is removing the row which has NA value **only if** the row is duplicate (which means we have another row with the same **PID** and **List.year**.
In some cases like the first row, since there is no same row with **PID** 003-913-627 and **List.Year** 2000 the NA shouldn't be removed. The expected result for the above data frame is:

```
   P.I.D..     Status List.year CURRENT_LAND_VALUE CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE
   <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>              <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1 003-913-627 X           2000                 NA                        NA
 2 003-913-627 T           2010            1578000                   1201000
 4 003-913-627 S           2018            2814000                    901000
 5 003-913-627 S           2002                 NA                        NA
 6 003-913-627 T           2007             390000                    282000
 7 003-913-627 T           2007             295000                    180000
 8 003-913-627 S           2008             464000                    391000
 9 003-913-627 S           2008             339000                    246000
10 003-913-627 X           2009             339000                    246000
11 003-913-627 X           2009             464000                    391000
```

In summary: I want to remove rows that have NA in "CURRENT_LAND_VALUE" and "CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE" only if there is already a row with same "PID" and "List.Year" which has actual value for "CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE" or "CURRENT_LAND_VALUE"

how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `summarise` after grouping can be used here as `dplyr` version `>= 1.0` can return more than one row per group.  Here, we can use the grouping columns, and then do the `summarise` `across` the numeric columns to return the non-NA elements if at least one of them is non-NA or else return the `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(`P.I.D..`, Status, List.year) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric),  
     ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else .[complete.cases(.)]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#   P.I.D..     Status List.year CURRENT_LAND_VALUE CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE
#   <chr>       <chr>      <int>              <dbl>                     <dbl>
# 1 003-913-627 S           2002                 NA                        NA
# 2 003-913-627 S           2008             464000                    391000
# 3 003-913-627 S           2008             339000                    246000
# 4 003-913-627 S           2018            2814000                    901000
# 5 003-913-627 T           2007             390000                    282000
# 6 003-913-627 T           2007             295000                    180000
# 7 003-913-627 T           2010            1578000                   1201000
# 8 003-913-627 X           2000                 NA                        NA
# 9 003-913-627 X           2009             339000                    246000
#10 003-913-627 X           2009             464000                    391000
```

Details - `across` loops over multiple columns.  Inside it, the first expression can be columns of interest.  We could use `everything()` if all the rest of the columns needs to be loop or a expression to check the `type` of the column and if it meets only do the looping (`where(is.numeric)`), then we create a lamdba expression (`~` - function(x) equivalent), and use some condition `if/else`.  It may not be needed, but it is just an option to prevent it from failing when some columns have only `NA`.  In the `else`, we subset the column with non-NA elements (`.[complete.cases(.)]`).

An assumption is that it will return the same length for each column, or else can be wrapped in a `list`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(P.I.D.. = c("003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", 
"003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", 
"003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627"), Status = c("X", 
"T", "S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "S", "S", "X", "X"), List.year = c(2000L, 
2010L, 2018L, 2018L, 2002L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2009L), CURRENT_LAND_VALUE = c(NA, 1578000L, NA, 2814000L, NA, 
390000L, 295000L, 464000L, 339000L, 339000L, 464000L), 
CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE = c(NA, 
1201000L, NA, 901000L, NA, 282000L, 180000L, 391000L, 246000L, 
246000L, 391000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: I'm trying to comprehend this great expression for `summarise`; could you explain its behavior? I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: Thanks, akrun. I copied your code but got an error regarding parentheses. Since your code in way more sophisticated than my knowledge I was not sure where I should add parenthese. Can you please help with it? Also, I appreaciate if you can explain more so I relaize how this code is working

Comment: @Roozbeh_you I checked again, by copy/pasting and running the code.  It is working for me.  Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I would use `>= 1.0` for `dplyr`

Comment: @akrun.  [1] ‘1.0.2’ so I guess I am fine on that side. Not sure when I copy and paste it, it is shown as `unmatched opening brackets`

Comment: @Roozbeh_you I tried couple of times though, but it is working

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is due to the way you are joining the two data frames, but without being able to produce it, my first thought is that you could do something like:

```
df %>% 
  distinct(`P.I.D.`, CURRENT_LAND_VALUE, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(CURRENT_LAND_VALUE))
```

The `distinct()` would give you the distinct inputs with the combinations of the `P.I.D` column and the `CURRENT_LAND_VALUE` column (thus if its duplicated, youd get the `NA` and the actual value as distinct rows) and then from there you could safely remove any `NA` values (assuming the `NA`s are only from the duplication and it isn't else where in the data).

If there are `NA`s naturally occurring then it would get more tricky and I would focus on shaping the `full_join` into a different type of join.

EDIT: I just noticed naturally occurring `NA`s do exist. My solution is less helpful then.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
subset(within(df, {
  pk <- as.integer(as.factor(paste0(P.I.D.., List.year)))
  pk_cnt <- ave(pk, pk, FUN = length)
}), pk_cnt == 1 | !(is.na(CURRENT_LAND_VALUE) & is.na(CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE)),
select = names(df))
```

Data:

```
   df <-  structure(list(P.I.D.. = c("003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", 
    "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627", 
    "003-913-627", "003-913-627", "003-913-627"), Status = c("X", 
    "T", "S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "S", "S", "X", "X"), List.year = c(2000L, 
    2010L, 2018L, 2018L, 2002L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2009L), CURRENT_LAND_VALUE = c(NA, 1578000L, NA, 2814000L, NA, 
    390000L, 295000L, 464000L, 339000L, 339000L, 464000L), CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE = c(NA, 
    1201000L, NA, 901000L, NA, 282000L, 180000L, 391000L, 246000L, 
    246000L, 391000L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep those rows that have only one row in a group or do not have `NA` value in both `CURRENT_LAND_VALUE` and `CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(P.I.D.., List.year) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 | !(is.na(CURRENT_LAND_VALUE) & is.na(CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE)))

#    P.I.D..     Status List.year CURRENT_LAND_VALUE CURRENT_IMPROVEMENT_VALUE
#   <chr>       <chr>      <int>              <int>                     <int>
# 1 003-913-627 X           2000                 NA                        NA
# 2 003-913-627 T           2010            1578000                   1201000
# 3 003-913-627 S           2018            2814000                    901000
# 4 003-913-627 S           2002                 NA                        NA
# 5 003-913-627 T           2007             390000                    282000
# 6 003-913-627 T           2007             295000                    180000
# 7 003-913-627 S           2008             464000                    391000
# 8 003-913-627 S           2008             339000                    246000
# 9 003-913-627 X           2009             339000                    246000
#10 003-913-627 X           2009             464000                    391000
```